# Xamarin Froms El motor de depuración seleccionado no es compatible con ningún código que se esté ejecutando

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, depuración

Amigos no sé que hice pero ahora obtengo este error cada que trato de compliar mi app, alguna idea?

> El motor de depuración seleccionado no es compatible con ningún código que se esté ejecutando en el hilo actual (por ejemplo, solo se está ejecutando código de tiempo de ejecución nativo).
>   Unhandled Exception:
>
> Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Comment: ¿Actualizaste paquetes `nuget`? ¿Ejecutaste Visual Studio con permisos de administrador?

Comment: si Fred si ejecuté como admin y si actualizé

Comment: @fredyfx sabes que ocaciona este tipo de errores, estoy seguro haber tenido uno similar antes, pero no recuerdo como lo solucioné u.u

Comment: Si actualizaste, entonces hiciste algo, ergo, "no sé qué hice" está fuera de contexto.

Comment: ¿Intentaste activar `MultiDex` ?

Comment: cuando corro mi proyecto me aperce en la salida justo al principop
>La aplicación Android se está depurando.
El motor de depuración no admite condiciones de excepción. Las condiciones se omitirán.
y luego me muestra los plugins que instalé y qu eestá deshechando

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78811/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-e-rawrdriguez-ophanim).